# Спарсенные данные яндекс новостей не идут в Телеграм канал

Tags: python, парсер, telegram, beautiful-soup, telethon

Сижу ломаю голову, создал приложение телеграмм которое берет посты с других ТГ каналов и перекидывает их в мой ТГ канал, но я написал еще парсер яндекс новостей, сам парсер работает, но вот почему то интегрировать его сюда у меня не получается, работает без ошибок, но по парсеру ничего не приходит

```
from telethon import functions, types
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests




api_id = ;;;№;";";
api_hash = ;№;№";"№;
client = TelegramClient("test", api_id, api_hash)
client.start()
print("STARTED")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=["moscowach", "moscowtop", 
                            "moscowlenta", "DtRoad", "mosmap", "kim_online_rus"]))

# Этот Def yandex как раз парсер яндекс новостей
def yandex(url):
    URL = 'https://newssearch.yandex.ru/news/' \
      'search?text=%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0&sortby=date'
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
    postes = soup.findAll("article", class_="news-search-story news-search__main-item mg-grid__item")

    for post in postes:
        title = post.a.text
        url = post.a['href']
        return url
@client.on(events.NewMessage(func = yandex))


async def normal_handler(event):
        if isinstance(event.chat, types.Channel,event.func):
            username = event.chat.username
            rdy = "@" + str(username)
            await client.send_message("https://t.me/kek3214", rdy)
            await client.send_message("https://t.me/kek3214", event.message)
            await client.send_message("https://t.me/kek3214", event.func)
            
        
        
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: А что у вас не так? Ошибка? А для чего это делать `@client.on(events.NewMessage(func = yandex))`? Вы на каждое сообщение вызываете вашу функцию yandex?

Comment: @gil9red ошибок никаких нету,но спарсенные данные с яндекс новостей просто не идут в телеграмм канал как и должны были, но если отдельно взять этот кусок кода и вызвать print на URL то выведет спарс ссылку с яндекса

@client.on(events.NewMessage(func = yandex)) с этим думал получется передать с def yandex, что бы он отправлял ссылки href в телеграмм канал, но не отправляет

Comment: Судя по описанию в документации https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/events.html#telethon.events.common.EventBuilder аргумент func нужен для определения нужно ли обрабатывать запрос, т.е. это кастомный фильтр. Не думаю, что вам это нужно... Я бы сделал нормальную функцию-обработчик и внутри ее вызывал функцию парсера и результат возвращал юзеру

Comment: @gil9red извиняюсь, немного не понял по функции обработчика, недавно начал с питоном работать, елси мы напишем новыйы def который будет это все обрабатывать, но мы же из другой не сможем взять

Comment: Вы можете создать на каждую команду обработчик, допустим на команду /moscow_news у вас одна функция-обработчик, на другую команду - другая функция-обработчик. Для такого в декораторе `@client.on` есть разные аргументы.
Или сделать одну функцию-обработчик, который обрабатывает все команды, но внутри обработчика смотрите какую команду вам прислали и выполняете нужные действия. Это насчет архитектуры бота.
Теперь о вашей функции парсинга, у нее не должно быть декоратора, чтобы из нее делали функцию-обработчик, это раз. Во-вторых, ее нужно вызывать в функция-обработчиках

Comment: Немного игрался с Telethon в своё время https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/39e6090e6a41c7ebe5982c027ffd7a248e858fa8/telegram__telethon__examples/%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA__wazzup/%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BA__wazzup.py#L28 вот тут проверяется регуляркой текст сообщения и если там встречается строка, совпадающая по шаблону, то будет вызвана функция-обработчик, к которой относится декоратор. Таких функций с декораторами можно сделать сколько понадобится.

Comment: Накидал пример того как я бы поменял ваш код в вопросе https://pastebin.com/dyRtLMRG

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо вам огромное, буду пробовать разбираться :)